# Wordpress emails are not delivered if the recipient email address has a non-traditional domain extension

Tags: email

For some reason, my wordpress site ([www.rain.works](http://www.rain.works)) appears to fail at sending any emails to email addresses that end in a non-traditional domain extension. I discovered this while trying to send a Woocommerce invoice to an @rain.works email account (which is managed by Google Workspace). Wordpress/Woocommerce says it sent the email, but no email arrives.

Using the "Check & Log Email" plugin and the "WP Mail Logging" plugin, I've tested sending emails from my Wordpress site to an @rain.works address and an @gmail.com address. Each time, I get a successful

> "The test email has been sent by WordPress."

message from the plugin, but only emails sent to the @gmail.com address actually arrive. I checked the Spam and All Mail filters, nothing there either.

Any ideas on what to try to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: it's very likely your email was intercepted long before ti reached googles mail servers, or as soon as it hit them, but there's very little information about how you're sending the emails on a technical level. Are you just relying on your hosts built in email via PHP that comes with WordPress? If so this shouldn't be considered to be reliable. Or do you use a service to send emails? SMTP? Emails from shared hosting plans are usually blocked as hacked sites on those servers are used to mail spam

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for the reply! My site has dedicated Linux hosting with a GoDaddy business plan. I was using the built in PHP email and did not know about the unreliability, thank you for pointing that out. I'm going to try installing WP Mail SMTP using the steps in [this article](https://wpforms.com/how-to-securely-send-wordpress-emails-using-gmail-smtp/) to get my emails sent from Google using SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue where contact form 7 emails were not reaching my google workspace email but was working fine with regular gmail. Turns out i had to add SPF records and email routing needed to be set to remote exchange server in cpanel. Note: my domain was hosted via hostgator.